# Get querystring to hidden input

Tags: javascript, html

How can i get querstring from url.

Example :

> http://www.bla.com/lp/index.html?ref=test

I want to get the "test" to hidden input that will send on form that i have (the form works great, all i need to know is how to get the value "test").

Javascript? Jquery?

I tried something funny i guess, without knowledge:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function getQueryString() {
            var query_string = {};
            var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
            var vars = query.split("&");
            for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
                    query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
                    var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
                    query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
                } else {
                    query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
                }
            } 
            return query_string;
        }
var queryString = getQueryString();

document.getElementById('new_leadsourcetext').value = queryString.ref; //myhiddeninput is  id of inpu
    </script>

<input type="hidden"  name="new_leadsourcetext" ID="new_leadsourcetext" />
```

Comment: similar one here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. Call the `getQueryString()` function which would return an object with key and value pair.

```
    function getQueryString() {
                var query_string = {};
                var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var vars = query.split("&");
                for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
                    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
                    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
                        query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
                        var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
                        query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
                    } else {
                        query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
                    }
                } 
                return query_string;
            }
    var queryString = getQueryString();

    document.getElementById('myhiddeninput').value = queryString.ref; //myhiddeninput is  id of input
```

Comment: thanks. how i call the function? just value="get..." ?

Comment: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (new_leadsourcetext="<script>getQueryStri...").

Comment: Set an ID (myhiddeninput) to the hidden input and use the last line to set the hidden input value.